# Expected prediction error - classification

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I am trying to solve the equation 2.19 to 2.20, but I'm struggling to find the end of the problem.

$ \sum [L(G,\hat{G}(X)]p(G,\hat{G}(X))$

$ \sum_k \sum_X [L(G,\hat{G}(X)]p(G)p(\hat{G}(X)|G)$

And then I cannot find the same equation if I try to replace by expected value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first expression should be a double sum over all possible values of $X$ and $G$. And the weights should be $Pr(G,X)$. They tell you to use this in the second to last sentence.

For your second sum you should try factoring the joint as  $Pr(G,X) = Pr(G|X)Pr(X).$ It might help to rewrite 2.20 as 
$$
\sum_x \left\{\sum_{k=1}^K L[\mathcal{G}_k, \hat{G}(x)]Pr(\mathcal{G}_k|x)\right\}Pr(x),
$$
if $X$ is discrete or
$$
\int \left\{\sum_{k=1}^K L[\mathcal{G}_k, \hat{G}(X)]Pr(\mathcal{G}_k|X)\right\}f(x)dx,
$$
if $X$ is continuous.